# Какие есть программы для удалённого мониторинга SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server

На просторах интернета почти ничего не нашёл(может плохо искал). Подскажите программы для удалённого мониторинга SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Единственным решением оказалось ПО от RedGate: SQL Monitor.